# Disable default magento free shipping method at frontend ONLY

Tags: magento2, admin, xml

> Store -> Settings -> Configuration -> Sales -> Shipping Methods -> Free Shipping

How can I disable this default feature of Magento in frontend only?

Comment: Set Enabled as no

Comment: Just set the value https://d.pr/free/i/upO1KA to **NO** , Flush Cache  and test it on frontend.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I updated the question. I only need it to be hidden in frontend

Comment: You can follow this blog http://www.amitbera.com/magento2-how-to-disabled-free-shipping-method-in-frontend/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a plugin for the free shipping method:

> etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <!-- PLUGINS: -->
    <type name="Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Freeshipping">
        <plugin name="mageworx_disable_free_shipping" type="MageWorx\DisableFreeShipping\Plugin\DisableFreeShippingOnFront"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> MageWorx\DisableFreeShipping\Plugin\DisableFreeShippingOnFront

```
<?php

namespace MageWorx\DisableFreeShipping\Plugin;

use Magento\Framework\App\State;

/**
 * Class DisableFreeShippingOnFront
 */
class DisableFreeShippingOnFront
{
    /**
     * @var State
     */
    private $state;

    /**
     * @param State $state
     */
    public function __construct(
        State $state
    ) {
        $this->state = $state;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Freeshipping $subject
     * @param callable $proceed
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest $request
     * @return \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result|bool
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function aroundCollectRates(
        \Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Freeshipping $subject,
        callable $proceed,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest $request
    ) {
        if ($this->state->getAreaCode() === \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND) {
            return false;
        }

        return $proceed($request);
    }
}
```

Don't forget to rename the `MageWorx\DisableFreeShipping` to yours vendor and module names.

Comment: Coming from m1 and is totally new at m2, what folder/path do I need to achieve this?

Comment: `vendor/module/etc/di.xml` and `vendor/module/Plugin/DisableFreeShippingOnFront.php` where the `vendor/module` should be replaced with your vendor-name and module-name.

Comment: I want to hide this on postal code. if postal code second value is zero then shipping method should hide.Can it is possible in this ?

Comment: @Yousaf yes, just change a condition in the plugin according your needs

Comment: Sir how i get postal code in this plugin . Can you update your code ?

Comment: @SiarheyUchukhlebau I used your code but free shipping is still showing on checkout page.

Comment: @Yousaf could you create an another question with code you are using?

Comment: @SiarheyUchukhlebau https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/301435/magento-2-3-how-to-hide-only-free-shipping-methods-based-on-postal-code Check this

Comment: @Yousaf I've added my answer in your question.

Comment: I want to disable the shipping methods on the checkout page only at the frontend not only on the other frontend sites,As I have some custom work in the customer account page

Comment: @RanaZain This will be difficult because updating the shipping method at checkout is done through the API, so you won't be able to detect the actual page the request came from.

Comment: anything that can help me

Comment: I want to use only one shipping method at checkout everything else remains same